# Magento 2: After using composer to install, can the "update" folder be deleted?

Tags: magento2, composer

After installing Magento 2 using the composer method, the update folder that is used to create the project with remains. I cannot see any reason to keep it after installing the composer dependencies.

Is it safe to delete?

Comment: It depends. The update folder contains the updater application which is how both components and the Magento system software are updated.

If you're certain you will always perform updates from the command line, I guess it's OK to delete it. However, I'm not sure what will happen next time you update Magento; there might be an error or the updater might come back.

Comment: @SteveJohnson That is, the update folder is only used within the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to make it inaccessible. That way you make sure modules that depend on the `update` application to be (physically) present, still work.

This can be achieved in 2 different ways:

- Make `pub` your document root (best)
- Deny access from `update` directory

After doing this, it'd be nice to make a module which removes the inaccessible link to the update application in the admin.