# Magento 2: Origin of the Update Folders

Tags: magento2, composer, web-setup-wizard

If I install Magento 2 via composer, I end up with a **root level** folder named `update/`

This contains the stand-alone updater application.

Where do the updater come from?  I know Magento's composer installer copies a lot of stuff out of the

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base
```

module, but the `update` application isn't in this this folder.  In fact, none of the files in the `update` application appear anywhere in `vendor` folder. (or do they?)

Does anyone know where these files come from, and what puts them on your system when installing Magento via the `composer.phar create-project` method?

Comment: I think it was in the project repository itself. So does not have to be copied from vendor. No time to verify for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full details are in [this old article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_composer_plugins/) (self link), but here's the high level overview.

When you say

```
composer create-project --no-install --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition my-magento2
```

you're telling Composer to download the `magento/project-community-edition` package and drop its contents directly in the `my-magento2` folder.  In addition to containing the `composer.json` file with all the Magento 2 packages listed, the `magento/project-community-edition` package includes the updated application in a top level `update` folder.

Comment: After update can we delete this update folder ? or it will be come in use for future update.

Comment: @PankajPareek Sounds like you have a new question, not a comment on the old question.

Comment: [After using composer to install, can the “update” folder be deleted?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/101923/12971)

Answer (score 3):

It is part of the project-community-edition zip file. If you look into it (easy to get from composer cache dir), you will see the following:

```
composer.json
update/
.gitignore
```